# compute the difference between avg rates

Tags: oracle

I need to find the difference between average rate of `staff` table  and non `staff` table in the last 12 months.

Here is what I have so far:

```
select  person.pid, 
        person.firstname, 
        person.lastname,
        AVG(RATING_RECORD.RATE)
from person, 
     client, 
     staff, 
     policy,
     COVERAGE,
     RATING_RECORD
where person.PID = client.PID  and  
      staff.pid = person.pid and 
      policy.SID =staff.SID and 
      COVERAGE.PNO = policy.PNO and
      COVERAGE.COID = RATING_RECORD.COID;
```

Now i have came to this

```
select  person.pid,
    person.FIRSTNAME,
    AVG(RATING_RECORD.RATE)
from person 
    join client on person.pid = client.pid 
    join staff on person.pid = staff.pid  
    join policy on staff.sid = policy.sid
    join coverage on policy.PNO = coverage.PNO
    join RATING_RECORD on coverage.COID = RATING_RECORD.COID
where policy.EXPIRYDATE between '12-NOV-13' and '12-nov-14 '
group by person.PID, person.FIRSTNAME;
```

but the thing is with this it only shows 3 results not the whole list?

going off the comments i came up with this, i took the client join out and came up with 
13 results

```
select  person.pid,
person.FIRSTNAME,
AVG(RATING_RECORD.RATE)
from person 

join staff on person.pid = staff.pid  
join policy on staff.sid = policy.sid
join coverage on policy.PNO = coverage.PNO
join RATING_RECORD on coverage.COID = RATING_RECORD.COID

where policy.EXPIRYDATE between '12-NOV-13' and '12-nov-14 '
group by person.PID, person.FIRSTNAME;
```

but how do i put the client back in to give me staff and non staff?

Comment: can you please be more explicit, define staff and non staff. Thanks

Comment: being new to this i dont what you mean by define?

Comment: which colums you want to show?

Comment: How does the database represent whether a person is staff or non staff? For example, can a person be both staff and a client? Your query, as it stands, will return only those people whose `PID`s are found in both the `STAFF` and `CLIENT` tables.

Comment: oh right i understand better now i want to show both staff and non staff and if they are in both, show it twice

Comment: theres 2 tables client and staff and client can be staff, i need the avg from both tables?

Comment: As your query stands, the `RATE` is retrieved via a join on the `STAFF` table. Therefore the rate will not be retrieved for any person who does not exist in `STAFF`. If non-staff are recorded in `CLIENT` but not in `STAFF`, no rate will be retrieved for them.

Comment: now how could i change it so it would recognize it?

Comment: The point is that only staff have ratings. Non-staff don't have ratings in this model, and the average of nothing is nothing.. Maybe if you were to supply information about all of your table structures, and some sample data, it might be easier to help?